# Failed to resolve: com.synnapps:carouselview:1.4.1 Show in Project Structure dialog Affected Modules: app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build-dependencies

**this is my build.gradle(:app)**

pls help me to solve this, i dont much about implementing dependencies in android studio

Failed to resolve: com.synnapps:carouselview:1.4.1 Show in Project Structure dialog Affected Modules: app

-this is what it says

Failed to resolve: com.synnapps:carouselview:1.4.1
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.taboanexpress"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.synnapps:carouselview:1.4.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same issue with a different library, but when trying to add the same library to an older project it works fine. I hope this small piece of info helps in finding a solution.